# When clicking button doesn't go to another view

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, android-button

I have ViewPager with 2 views (no fragments). I need that when I click to button at the first view it goes to another view. When I flip views it works. But if I want do this with button, it shows the first view only and doesn't go to another view.

activity class:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    private PickerView PickerView;
    private Button imageButton;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);

        pickerView = new PickerView(this);
        imageButton = pickerView.findViewById(R.id.next);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PickerActivity">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment xml file where is button: (this file is "inflating" in PickerView class)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
  />
```

Comment: Have you given the ViewPager the views to switch?

Comment: And hey, you can only switch views using ViewPager2. ViewPager only work with fragments if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @ Jason,What do you mean by "given the ViewPager the views to switch"? See, now I can switch views by flip.

Comment: `pickerView = new PickerView(this);` creates a new fragment in memory which does nothing related to current UI, so you have never clicked that button. Update question with code of **CustomPagerAdapter** may help.

Comment: @ i_A_mok, thanks to your comment I got an idea: I just deleted `pickerView = new PickerView(this)` and put `<Button>` `to activity_main.xml` and now I have what I need. Thanks!